# Should my mother apply in Canada for USA visitor visa?

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, canada

My mother is currently in Canada on a super visa and has been granted for stay up to 2 years. My brother, doing his Master's in the USA, has his convocation and my mother and I want to attend. We have all the necessary documents from him for the event.

I have been reading that the visa rejection rate is quite high when you are not applying from your home country. Is that true for Canada super visa holders as well? She has been granted for a stay for just to apply for a US visa.

I am a little confused; I do want her to travel with me to US for the convocation but don't want any visa rejections on her passport.

Comment: I do not know statistics specifically about super visas. However a super visa is a long stay visa. I would expect USA consular officers will treat it as something close to a residence permit and not like a normal short stay visitor visa. Hence I would expect a solid application to have close to the probability of success as applying in their home country.

Answer (score 1):

You should apply from where you are a resident and staying in Canada for about 2 years is long enough to be seen as a resident and for the visa officials to take your visa application as coming from a resident.

Just make sure she does include strong reasons to return to Canada and/or her home country, so it is clear she will not want to stay in the USA.